# Insert >1 rows of data from a table to another TempTable

Tags: sql-server

Since the result returns more than 1 row, it is not able to `INSERT INTO` the `@TEMP_ROW` table. I want all the rows to be inserted into the `@TEMP_ROW` table. Can I use a while loop? If yes, how? Or any other method?

```
DECLARE @TEMP_ROW TABLE
                  (
                        RSEQ INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                        ROWNO INT
                  )

INSERT INTO @TEMP_ROW (ROWNO) 
VALUES ((SELECT RowNo 
         FROM R2 
         WHERE R2.ReqID = 802 
           AND R2.RowNo IN (SELECT DISTINCT RowNo 
                            FROM R1 
                            WHERE ReqID = 802 
                              AND ((Fac IN ('ABC', 'ABCD') 
                                   AND NOM IN ('', '00', '0')) 
                               OR (Fac ='AAA'))
                              AND ROWLED = 'L'))
```

The error :

> SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `insert` from `select` syntax.

```
INSERT INTO @TEMP_ROW 
            (rowno) 
SELECT rowno 
FROM   r2 
WHERE  r2.reqid = 802 
       AND r2.rowno IN (SELECT DISTINCT rowno 
                        FROM   r1 
                        WHERE  reqid = 802 
                               AND ( ( fac IN ( 'ABC', 'ABCD' ) 
                                       AND nom IN ( '', '00', '0' ) ) 
                                      OR ( fac = 'AAA' ) ) 
                               AND rowled = 'L')
```